# weird output of dplyr::SETDIFF in r

Tags: r, dplyr, set-difference

I am trying to use setdiff function in dplyr, on these two dataframes:

```
t1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
names(t1) <- c("C1","C2")

t2 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(0,1,2))
names(t2) <- c("C1","C2")
```

But, I keep getting this output which I don't expect:

```
> setdiff(t2,t1)
  C1 C2
1  1  0
2  2  1
3  3  2
```

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is perfectly reasonable. First of all, `t1` contains three observations: `(1,1), (2,2)` and `(3,3)`. None of these is present in `t2`.

Now, `setdiff` is the set of `t2` without the set of `t1`. In this case, since none of the observations (rows) of `t1` are present in `t2`, `t_2 - t_1 = t2`.